# Why is my web app jumping to the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been playing around with a browser chat application and all is going well apart from being able to scroll up to see previous messages that go outside of the window, when I scroll up the scrollbar suddenly jumps to the bottom of the page again.

I've tried to remedy this by changing the .msg-are height from calc(100% - 102px); to auto but then the page loads right at the top with all messages out of view.

Any help is appreciated.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Messenger</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    html {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .msg-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px 0px 5px;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    .msg-area {
        height: calc(100% - 102px); /*This both fixes the scrolling problem but creates white space at the bottom of the page in doing so and hides messages */
        width: 100%;
        background-color:#F0F8FF;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .msginput {
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
        width: calc(100% - 20px);
        outline: none;
    }
    .bottom {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0px;
        border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
        background-color: #EBEBEB;
    }
    #whitebg {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #F0F8FF;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        opacity: 0.6;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    #loginbox {
        width: 600px;
        height: 350px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        background-color: #FFF;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        z-index: 1001;
        display: none;
    }
    h1 {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    button {
        background-color: #43ACEC;
        border: none;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 0px;
        width: 150px;
    }
    .buttonp {
        width: 150px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
    .msg {
        margin: 10px 10px;
        background-color: #f1f0f0;
        max-width: calc(45% - 20px);
        color: #000;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .msgfrom {
        background-color: #0084ff;
        color: #FFF;
        margin: 10px 10px 10px 55%;
    }
    .msgarr {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 8px solid transparent;
        border-right: 8px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 8px solid #f1f0f0;
        transform: rotate(315deg);
        margin: -12px 0px 0px 45px;
    }
    .msgarrfrom {
        border-bottom: 8px solid #0084ff;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 45px;
    }
    .msgsentby {
        color: #8C8C8C;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 4px 0px 0px 10px;
    }
    .msgsentbyfrom {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 12px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="checkcookie(); update();">
<div id="whitebg"></div>
<div id="loginbox">
<h1>Pick a username:</h1>
<p><input type="text" name="pickusername" id="cusername" placeholder="Pick a username" class="msginput"></p>
<p class="buttonp"><button onclick="chooseusername()">Choose Username</button></p>
</div>
<div class="msg-container">
    <div class="header">Messenger</div>
    <div class="msg-area" id="msg-area"></div>
    <div class="bottom"><input type="text" name="msginput" class="msginput" id="msginput" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) sendmsg()" value="" placeholder="Enter your message here ... (Press enter to send message)"></div>
</div>
<!--start JavaScript-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var msginput = document.getElementById("msginput");
var msgarea = document.getElementById("msg-area");
function chooseusername() {
    var user = document.getElementById("cusername").value;
    document.cookie="messengerUname=" + user
    checkcookie()
}
function showlogin() {
    document.getElementById("whitebg").style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById("loginbox").style.display = "inline-block";
}
function hideLogin() {
    document.getElementById("whitebg").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("loginbox").style.display = "none";
}
function checkcookie() {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("messengerUname") == -1) {
        showlogin();
    } else {
        hideLogin();
    }
}
function getcookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
function escapehtml(text) {
  return text
      .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
      .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
      .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
      .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
      .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}
function update() {
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    var username = getcookie("messengerUname");
    var output = "";
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                var response = xmlhttp.responseText.split("\n")
                var rl = response.length
                var item = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < rl; i++) {
                    item = response[i].split("\\")
                    if (item[1] != undefined) {
                        if (item[0] == username) {
                            output += "<div class=\"msgc\" style=\"margin-bottom: 30px;\"> <div class=\"msg msgfrom\">" + item[1] + "</div> <div class=\"msgarr msgarrfrom\"></div> <div class=\"msgsentby msgsentbyfrom\">Sent by " + item[0] + "</div> </div>";
                        } else {
                            output += "<div class=\"msgc\"> <div class=\"msg\">" + item[1] + "</div> <div class=\"msgarr\"></div> <div class=\"msgsentby\">Sent by " + item[0] + "</div> </div>";
                        }
                    }
                }
                msgarea.innerHTML = output;
                msgarea.scrollTop = msgarea.scrollHeight;
            }
        }
          xmlhttp.open("GET","get_messages.php?username=" + username,true);
          xmlhttp.send();
}
function sendmsg() {
    var message = msginput.value;
    if (message != "") {
        // alert(msgarea.innerHTML)
        // alert(getcookie("messengerUname"))
        var username = getcookie("messengerUname");
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                message = escapehtml(message)
                msgarea.innerHTML += "<div class=\"msgc\" style=\"margin-bottom: 30px;\"> <div class=\"msg msgfrom\">" + message + "</div> <div class=\"msgarr msgarrfrom\"></div> <div class=\"msgsentby msgsentbyfrom\">Sent by " + username + "</div> </div>";
                msginput.value = "";
            }
        }
          xmlhttp.open("GET","update_messages.php?username=" + username + "&message=" + message,true);
          xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
setInterval(function(){ update() }, 500);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could not figure out much about your problem.  One thing you should change is class named "bottom". It is a css reserved word.  https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/css/keywords.html

Comment: I've found out that the cause is the fact that the ajax is updating the page every half a second. I need some way to stop this and only update when a new message is posted.